# Hasse-Minkowski and Rational Solutions to General Quadratic Polynomials

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics

Hasse-Minkowski is stated as a theorem about quadratic forms. I know it implies an existence criteria for rational solutions to quadratic forms. I assume via homogenization this would mean it also implies a criteria for rational solutions to any general quadratic equation, but I'm having a hard time finding a reference that explicitly says this. Am I missing something, or just overthinking this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. According to a very useful (but deleted!) answer below, this stated in "Symmetric Bilinear Forms, by John Minor and D. Husemoller, page 125."

Comment: I don't know if homogeneizing would work: say you have a polynomial $P = \sum a_{ij} x_i x_j  +  \sum b_j x_j + c$  in $n$ variables, then you could consider the quadratic form $q = \sum a_{ij} x_i x_j  +  \sum b_j x_j Z_j + c T^2$ in $2n + 1$ variables. If $q(x_1, ..., x_n, Z_1, ...., Z_n, T) = 0$ for some non-zero vector of $x,Z,T$, then you would like to replace $x_i$ by $x_i / Z_i$ to ensure that $Z_i = 1$. But what if $Z_i=0$ for some $i$? And what about making $T=1$?